# How do I save CSV data to variables based on a ListBox selection?

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a drop down list in my script that gets populated by the "name" column in a CSV file. I'd like to save the information in the other columns that go with that name into variables to be used later.

For example (bullets are there so they show underneath each other, showed as one line otherwise):

- Name,Address,PhoneNumber,Email
- Bob,1234 Bob Rd,123-4567,bob@email.com
- Bill,5678 Bill Ave,246-8024,bill@email.com

The drop down list would show Bob and Bill. Based on what I pick I'd like the rest of their info to be saved into 3 different variables, $Address, $PhoneNumber, and $Email.

I've got as far as importing the CSV into the array and sorting them alphabetically.

```
$Customers = @(Import-CSV "$dir\Apps\Customers.csv")
$Array = $Customers.name | Sort-Object
```

Here's part of the drop down box code:

```
ForEach ($Choice in $Array) {

    [void] $companybox.Items.Add($Choice)

}
```

After that I can't figure out how to grab the correct information based on what's been chosen when I click a button.

Here's the button code:

```
$handler_gobutton_Click = { $company = $companybox.SelectedItem
                            ....
                          }
```

I have a few If statements in there right now for an earlier solution that doesn't use CSV's, but I'd like to move to a CSV file if possible.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm thinking what I need to do is somehow find the array count number based on the name column. After that I should be able to save $array[0].address into a variable, for example. Finding how to compare the variable with the name in it to the name in the array and from that getting the count number is coming up empty so far... Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

```
$handler_gobutton_Click = {
$company = $companybox.SelectedItem
$index = [array]::IndexOf($customers.name,$company)
If ($customers[$index].uninstall -eq "True") { $uninstallbox.checked = $True }
... and so on
}
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/t1928/finding_array_index_number/